# Getting items from lists for bar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, visualization

hoping someone can help accessing individual items from lists.

I'm attempting to create a simple bar chart, counting frequencies of a user inputted column from a csv file.

This is fine and I can show a bar chart fine, but I cannot seem to understand how to arrange the data ascending/descending along the x-axis. I have code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import sys
import csv
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

filename = sys.argv[1]

data = []

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = reader.next()
    header = [head.replace(" ", "_").lower() for head in header]
    data = [row for row in reader]

for field in header:
    print field

header_name = raw_input("Select field from above: ")
column_no = header.index(header_name)

empty = []

for datarow in data:
    empty.append(datarow[column_no])

counted = Counter(empty)
sorted_counted = sorted(counted.items(), key=itemgetter(0))

print sorted_counted
```

Which gets me to the point of having a sorted list of items:
[('AK', 6), ('AR', 1), ('AZ', 9), ('CA', 72), ('CO', 8), ('CT', 5), ('DC', 1), ('FL', 28), ('GA', 7), ('HI', 4), ('IA', 1), ('ID', 4), ('IL', 15), ('IN', 9), ('KS', 5), ('KY', 1), ('LA', 9), ('MA', 12), ('MD', 17), ('ME', 3), ('MI', 14), ('MN', 7), ('MO', 4), ('MS', 4), ('MT', 1), ('NC', 8), ('ND', 1), ('NE', 2), ('NH', 1), ('NJ', 52), ('NM', 2), ('NV', 2), ('NY', 46), ('OH', 22), ('OK', 1), ('OR', 6), ('PA', 29), ('RI', 5), ('SC', 3), ('SD', 1), ('TN', 10), ('TX', 32), ('UT', 1), ('VA', 7), ('WA', 8), ('WI', 11), ('WY', 3)]

Because I couldn't sort of the dictionary "counted".

So then my plan was to take all of the state designators "CO" "CT" "DC" etc and put the in one list, and all the numerical value in another.
From that point I can then plot the two lists on a chart, and it should be ordered by state name alphabetically.

There's probably an easier way to do this, if so would be really good to hear.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so have it working the way i want.

It was a list of tuples that needed splitting and did not know about the zip command. so now i have two separate lists, but related data positions.